# Trying to disable mouse accel and I have a question

Tags: usb, mouse, 14.10

Can someone tell me how do I figure which of these 2 is actually my mouse so that I can actually turn off mouse accel ? .Why the hell does it show 2 A4TECH USB DEVICE?

[image: http://imgur.com/7bJkwep]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

virtual core pointer is going to be you mouse.